# How to return a HTML template from a template.FuncMap?

Tags: templates, go

I asked this question upon https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/CUbdaHkESJk but received no replies.

I'm writing a [Web based media viewer](https://github.com/kaihendry/lk) and I've hit a snag about how to mark up different media.

My current code here: https://github.com/kaihendry/lk/blob/5de96f9fe012e9894deef7b9924f96dd8d9c806c/main.go#L181
is certainly wrong. I am puzzled how to use a template here in light of https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute

All the examples I see of using template.FuncMap just use strings...

Reduced example: https://play.golang.org/p/mAue8SDDw6

Ideally I would use html templates here and not fmt.Sprintf. Yes, I realise I am not HTML escaping the filename which is wrong, but I am not sure how to use HTML templates again from this function.

Thanks in advance for any guidance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate the *logic* (function) from *presentation* (template). 
The function registered in `template.FuncMap` should not depends on template as its input to produce an output. If you want to return HTML template as the function output, you should generate it manually (using `fmt.Sprintf`, etc.).

In your case, you can simply register a function to check the media type, then generate different output using template's [`{{if}}`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions)  action. The function may looks like:

```
func matchType(ext, s string) bool {
    return strings.ToLower(ext) == strings.ToLower(path.Ext(s))
}
```

and the template looks like:

```
{{ range .Media }}<p>
    {{if . | matchType ".jpg"}}<img src={{.}}>
    {{else if . | matchType ".mp4"}}<video controls src={{.}}></video>
    {{else}}{{.}}
    {{end}}</p>
{{ end }}
```

A working example based on your reduced example: https://play.golang.org/p/U64_7UHZQU

Comment: Thank you, the approach seems a quite bit better, but I am not sure if I like the "if,else,else,else" type structure.